# JavaScript REGEX Match all and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am coding a simple templating function in javascript.

I have my template loading fine, now is the part when I need to parse the content to the placeholders.

an example of a template is:

```
{{name}} is {{age}}
```

These are dynamic, so ideally I want to use regex to match and replace the placeholders based on their names, e.g.

{{name}} is to be replaced by content loaded in a javascript array, e.g.

```
data.name

data.age
```

This is my regex: `/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/`

This is working fine, but after a lot of searching I can't find a defined way of iterating through every regex match.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Is this what you're trying to make?](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Comment: similar but not exactly.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, first you'll need the `g` flag on the regex. This tells JavaScript to replace *all* matched values. Also you can supply a function to the `replace` method. Something like this:

```
var result = str.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function(match, token) {
    return data[token];
});
```

The second parameter matches the first subgroup and so on.

Comment: +1... Wrapped your code into a function and used eval to evaluate multi level objects... http://jsfiddle.net/hU7e2/  Can run arbitrary code as well. So be careful :) http://jsfiddle.net/hU7e2/1/

Comment: I have this syntax =>.   ${name}
can you please provide a regex to also cover this

Comment: That would be `/\$\{(\w+?)\}/g`. You should read up on Regular Expressions, they're a very handy tool to have in your belt.

Answer (score 13):

```
var data = {
    name: 'zerkms',
    age: 42
};

var str = '{{name}} is {{age}}'.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function(i, match) {
    return data[match];
});

console.log(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zDJLd/